# Change Default Stack Size Node.js

Tags: node.js, v8

How do i change the default `stack_size` in of node ?

I have already tried running the command `node --stack_size=32000` and  `ulimit -s 32000`.

Comment: How do you know that this isn't working?

Comment: I'm using `node --stack-size=1000000000` to push it to the limit, works well for me. :)

Comment: I know its not working cause when I run command node --stack_size=32000 app.js its works fine with any errors. But if I run only node app.js its give me memory error and the app exists.

I need to set a default value so that I dont need to provide stack_size argument everytime

Comment: node --stack-size=8192 is the max value on my Ubuntu Server. Anything more than that doesn't increase the max recursion of my functions. Note that the unit of --stack-size is KB, so that's about 8 MB. In Windows I can't get more than 1 MB.